# django-tenant-schema enable Admin module for all tenants

Tags: python, django

I am setting up django with multitenant architecture. I went through the https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
instruction and get to the point that have inital startup screen.
What I want to achieve is to enable admin module for each tenant.
my in settings.py I have following:

```
#Application definition
SHARED_APPS = (
    'tenant_schemas',  # mandatory, should always be before any django app
    'customers', # you must list the app where your tenant model resides in

    'django.contrib.contenttypes',

    # everything below here is optional

)

TENANT_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',

    # your tenant-specific apps
    # 'myapp.hotels',
    # 'myapp.houses',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'tenant_schemas',
    'customers',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

TENANT_MODEL = "customers.Client"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'tenant_schemas.middleware.TenantMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sitemanager.urls'
PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF = 'sitemanager.urls_public'
```

when trying to open http://localhost:8000/admin getting error:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/login/
Site matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 2.1.2
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Site matching query does not exist.
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

What am I missing in configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `PUBLIC_SCHEMA_NAME = 'public'` sort the problem.

Comment: There is more to add to this. If you have `django.contrib.sites` then your default site in `django_site` table will be set to example.com. And then it will not work. Removing `django.contrib.sites` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think django.contrib.sites should be in SHARED_APPS.

Kudos for using django-tenant-schema +1

Comment: Sorry about that, I haven't used it for a long time, I remember about PUBLIC_SCHEMA_NAME too now. Don't forget to accept your own answer to close the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Then to create a superuser :`./manage.py tenant_command createsuperuser`
Might be handy.

Answer (score 0):

to solve such issue, add PUBLIC_SCHEMA_NAME = 'public' and remove django.contrib.sites from both INSTALLED_APPS and SHARED_APPS.